# Proving something on the Schwarz space and extending to $L^p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am taking a graduate Harmonic Analysis course without having taken a Functional Analysis course (supposed to take it next semester). I have done fine by reading up on whatever odds and bits I have needed but a common manner of proof is proving something on the Schwarz space (or some other dense subspace) and extending to $L^P$ space. I haven't seen these before so I am hoping I can be directed to some reference material with perhaps some prototypical examples of such proofs. Cheers.

Comment: Your question is too vague. The general gist of such proofs is that Schwartz functions endowed with the $p$-norm are dense in $L^p$, so if you prove for example that a continuous operator is zero on Schwartz functions you know that it is zero on all of $L^p$ by a topological argument.